# I can't center listView in android

Tags: listview, layout, android-linearlayout, gravity, layout-gravity

[ListView not being centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bv1yd.jpg)

Buddy, What's the problem in this listView? I can't solve the problem no matter what I do.

Answer (score 0):

can you try replace this
 `android:layout_width="match_parent"`  in `ListView`

to this 
`android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

I hope it will work with you .